# Validation switcher

Tags: django, validation, checkbox, model

I need a little tip.
I use the field validator in the django model.
But sometimes there is a case when I need to turn off the check.
I thought that a simple check box that would turn off checking could be convenient.
Can you tell me where it will be better to place a handler for check box.

Comment: Are you talking about the validation in the Django admin site, or in a form in you main site?

Comment: I use django. But I use 3 api: restAPI, DjangoAdmin and third party CMS. As I understand best way is to place handler in model level. It allow to process actions from all APIs. Maybe checkbox can be a parameter not a field,  which will clear a validator list in other field.  But i still hope about more native design )))